# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 10.4 and have 2 tables:

person:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  nationality character varying(100),
  name character varying(100),
  age integer
);
```

country:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  demonym character varying(50),
  name character varying(50)
);
```

This is the query that I am trying to run:

```
select "c"."name",
    (SELECT row_to_json(r) FROM (
      SELECT
        COALESCE(sum(CASE WHEN p."nationality"='finn' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as "1",
        COALESCE(sum(CASE WHEN p."nationality"='spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as "2"

      FROM "person" as p
      WHERE "p"."nationality"="c"."demonym"
      ) as r) as "nationalitiesCount"
from "country" as c         
WHERE 'nationalitiesCount'::json->'1' > 10
```

This yields an error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
>
> LINE 11: WHERE 'nationalitiesCount'::json->'1' > 10
>
> DETAIL:  Token "nationalitiesCount" is invalid.
>
> CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: nationalitiesCount

The second line has the first `'` highlighted as the code which causes the error to appear.

**Question:** How could the error be rectified?

Comment: Please fix your question. The error msg does not fit the broken query. Would be `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"` due to the missing comma. Show your actual query and always disclose the version of Postgres in use. And show the table definition of `"Average"`. That aside, `'salaries'->>'1'::json` does not even begin to make sense. You might want to start in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter editing the question. Through the second link in 9.43, the table shows that in order to access prop values of json object, we need to have this syntax: `'{"a":1,"b":2}'::json->>'b'` This is what I was trying to replicate and what you can see in my code snippet above.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Corrected.

Comment: This is a lost case. Fixing the syntax error (identifiers need double quotes) is getting us nowhere. Your subquery is correlated on `nationality`, and yet you try to count different nationalities at the same time. Doesn't make sense. Your edit improved the question, but you still don't tell what the query should achieve. So we can't even begin to try and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that references to columns should not be in single quotes, though they can be / sometimes have to be in double quotes, which is why it doesn't like 'nationalitiesCount'::json->'1'. The second is that the column name nationalitiesCount is defined in the SELECT part of the query and can't be referenced in the WHERE clause of the query where it's defined, so you can move your query into a subquery so you can reference it outside of the subquery.

```
select *
from (select "c"."name",
    (SELECT row_to_json(r) 
     FROM (
      SELECT
       COALESCE(sum(CASE WHEN p."nationality"='finn' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as "1",
       COALESCE(sum(CASE WHEN p."nationality"='spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as "2"

       FROM "person" as p
       WHERE "p"."nationality"="c"."demonym"
     ) as r) as "nationalitiesCount"
from "country" as c 
) t
WHERE (t."nationalitiesCount"->>'1')::integer > 10
```